# How to grant permission to certain files using .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

In the wordpress site I'm developing are my digital products stored in the uploads folder. I found out that this folder is publicly accessible when you know the url.
So when I enter http://my-site.com/wp-content/uploads I get a directory listing with all files exposed en simple to download. That is not what I want of course. I found a solution on the internet using this .htaccess code:

```
IndexIgnore *
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?my-site\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx) [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx)$ http://my-site.com
```

This works fine, everyone who is entering the url is redirected to the homepage.
Downloads of purchased goods are going fine to because the request is from within the site. However there is a logo file (used in the WooCommerce emails) which must be accessible. Right now the logo is not displayed in the emails because the system decide that it is not a request from within the site and the access is denied. Can I grant access to this file using an updated version of the code above and if yes what changes do I have to make? Please advice.

HTH from you soon.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can disable directory listing in .htaccess by using `Options -Indexes`. For more information about it please refer to https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings

Then, using the header `Referer` as a security measure can be dangerous as it can be easily changed.

You should consider replacing this part by a script which manage a kind of access-list to allow or deny the access to the original file (e.g. temporary key like on Amazon S3).

Comment: In the code above I managed to 'hide' all directories with `IndexIgnore *`, that works fine in my opinion. I'm not sure what you mean by Header `referer` is not secure. In what way could someone from elswere change it? Don't you need access to the folder for it? Would you be so kind te explain it a bit more?

Comment: The header `Referer` is sent by the client, so the client can change it as it wants. You can read more about this header here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer and referer spoofing here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spoofing